# Declaring variable inside of the echo statement(SYNTAX ERROR)

Tags: php, html

If it is possible that I can declare variable inside of the echo, if yes please correct my syntax, or any idea of it.

```
     $from = "pacificskybeachresort@gmail.com";
     $email = $_GET['text_email'];
     $subject = "Creating Account";
   //here's my problem the message code


$message = echo "<a href='https://www.pacificskybeachresort.com/Website/fe/home/index.php?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&lastname=$lastname&firstname=$firstname&number=$number&address=$address'</a>";

     mail($email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);
```

PS: The message will be https://www.pacificskybeachresort.com/Website/fe/home/index.php?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&lastname=$lastname&firstname=$firstname&number=$number&address=$address', but I want to echo a  tag.

Comment: Show us the actual error.

Comment: Just get rid of the echo?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Jesus, it's been a long day I didn't even see that x.x

Comment: echo does not return anything. $message will be nulled out.

Comment: What I will do? I want to echo a **<a>This is message</a>**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the variable in your email as well as echo it to the screen:

1. Define the variable

   ```
   $message = "<a href ...
   ```
2. Echo the variable

   ```
   echo $message;
   ```
3. Send it in the email.

   ```
   mail($email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);
   ```

(2 and 3 can be in either order; it doesn't matter.)

A separate problem is that your HTML isn't properly formed. The opening `<a>` tag is missing its closing `>` and there's no text between the `<a>` and the `</a>`.

I separated the URL into a different variable to make it easier to see what needs to happen with the HTML part.

```
$url = "https://www.pacificskybeachresort.com/Website/fe/home/index.php?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&lastname=$lastname&firstname=$firstname&number=$number&address=$address";


// close the a tag here   ↓
$message = "<a href='$url'>Whatever text you want</a>";
// link text goes between the tags ↑
```

Comment: Sir the output is like this 

<a href='https://www.pacificskybeachresort.com/Website/fe/home/index.php?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&lastname=$lastname&firstname=$firstname&number=$number&address=$address'</a>

i want to echo the <a> tag

Comment: What do you want the text to be in the a tag?

Comment: like this

Code: <a href=https//www.example.com>Text</a>

Output: **Text** 

PS: the user will only see the text not the whole code

Comment: Sir the output is still  the a tag

Comment: Were you trying to echo just the text without the a tag? And what are you trying to send in the email? The a tag, or the text only?

Comment: The text only, yes im trying to send it in email.

Answer (score 1):

If you want echo the string and assign it as a variable in the same line you can do it like this:

```
<?php
echo ($message =  "<a href='https://www.pacificskybeachresort.com/Website/fe/home/index.php?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&lastname=$lastname&firstname=$firstname&number=$number&address=$address'</a>");
```

And if you want to display the HTML text as a plain text, use the function **htmlspecialchars**

```
<?php
echo ($message =  htmlspecialchars("<a href='https://www.pacificskybeachresort.com/Website/fe/home/index.php?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&lastname=$lastname&firstname=$firstname&number=$number&address=$address'</a>"));
```

Comment: wait sir I'll try

Comment: sir the output is like encrypting text, I mean the code is <a href=www.example.com>This is the **Text** </a> and the output will be **This is the Text** <-- this one only